# dynamically returning views by a foreach loop

Tags: database, laravel, dynamic, foreach, controller

I have a foreach loop that runs  by my database:

```
<div id="nav" >
  @foreach(\App\Categories::whereNull('parent_id')->get() as $category)
     <a id="link1" href="{{ route('showCategory' , $category->id) }}" ><div class="link">{{ $category->name }}</div></a>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

I want foreach link that adds by that it knows his path to the blades dynamically.

What should I do here?

My web.php:

```
Route::get('/category/{category}', 'PagesController@showCategory')->name('showCategory');
```

My controller:

```
public function showCategory(Categories $category) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to create a link for each category which goes to a page that displays more information about the selected category.

Your blade file in which you create the links for all the categories seems fine to me, but I'd recommend changing your route file to this:

`Route::get('/category/{id}', 'PagesController@showCategory')->name('showCategory');`

Then for your `showCategory` function, you would need something like this:

```
public function showCategory($id) {
    $category = Categories::find($id);

    // i used categories.show here, change it to whatever view you use
    return view('categories.show')->with('category', $category);
}
```

Then in your `categories.show` view, you can access the properties of the category like so:

`$category->id; // or whatever you want to display`

---

As per OP's request: the first 5 categories in the database that lead to their pages:

---

In your controller:

```
public function myFunction()
{
   $categories = Categories::all()->take(5)->get();

   return view('your.view')->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

In your blade view (assuming that the view for the category is at: `/category/id`):

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
   <a href="/category/{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.And if I have 5 different links and each one has a different 'href' how would you recommend to do it in the categories.show?

Comment: 5 different links in one category? Or 5 different categories leading to their pages?

Comment: 5 different categories leiding to their pages is what I mean.

Comment: Do you want 5 random categories from you database? All of them? Or the 5 first or 5 last.

Comment: First 5 categories.